# OpenGL or CUDA/OpenCL for raytracer?

Tags: opengl, cuda, opencl

I read that a lot of raytracers use CUDA or OpenCL. However, I don't know why modern( version 4.0+) OpenGL is not used.
I know that CUDA and OpenCL have more features, I think they are closer to the hardware, but... is this really useful for this purpose? If so, why?

Answer (score 3):

OpenGL design is all about getting points, lines or triangles rasterized to a frame buffer. Shaders are used to control this process, but ultimately its just rasterization. When rasterizing you take each triangle, one by one, determine where it is going to be in the framebuffer and then manipulate those specific pixels.

Raytracing or Path tracing is something entirely different. Instead of starting out with the triangles determining which pixels to touch, you start out with the pixels and for each pixel trace into the scene which geometry is relevant for the pixel. I.e. it's kind of complementary what OpenGL does. Hence trying to fit this into OpenGL is kind of barking up the wrong tree. You need to work with completely different data structures, your programs are structured differently than shaders. OpenCL and CUDA are much better suited for programming ray or path tracing algorithms.

Comment: I think the question still stands thoug... You can always just draw a quad in OpenGL and use a fragment shader...

Comment: @frankelot: a) you wouldn't draw a quad (i.e. two triangles glued together) to trigger a scissor rectangle wide execution of a fragment shader; you'd draw a single triangle that fully encompasses the scissor rect (my go-to tri for that is [(0,0),(2,0),(0,2)]). b) these day's you'd probably use a compute shader instead of a fragment shader (unless you want to render directly into a subset of a larger framebuffer).

Answer (score 1):

Both OpenGL and more generic parallel computing mechanisms such as OpenCL or CUDA can be used to implement all kinds of ray-casting, including Raytracing.  In fact, if you go to [Shadertoy](https://www.shadertoy.com/) you'll find a great many of the shaders there produce interesting 3D scenes and effects using only a single fragment shader, though mostly using ray marching rather than ray tracing.

With any kind of ray casting, you typically perform a lot of computation for every single pixel you're rendering.  Since no pixel depends on the output of any other pixel, and since the algorithm for each pixel is the same, this kind of problem is ideal for parallel processing, which is at the heart of what OpenCL is designed for.  You can also use OpenGL for parallel computing.  The main advantage for OpenGL here is that if you're attempting to render something in real-time, then you want the results of the computation to stay on the video card, resulting in display on an output device.

On the other hand, if you're doing non-realtime rendering, then OpenCL probably has more functionality and less overhead required to accomplish the task at hand.

In either case, the biggest problem is probably not the implementation of the renderer, but figuring out a way to express the scene description either directly in the rendering code, or load it from some scene descriptor file and encode it in some fashion that the rendering code can interpret within the OpenCL or OpenGL framework.  You cannot, for instance, simply load some XML or JSON scene description file and pass it to an OpenCL Kernel / OpenGL fragment shader.  Ultimately it ends up having to be expressed in terms of whatever kinds of structures and primitives you *can* express in the language you choose.